# Is there a way to automate event feedback using Civi and Drupal webform?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

What we are looking to do is find a neat way to create a process for sending out an automated email from Civi with a link to a form of some type for a feedback or evaluation on the event that a person has booked on. We would ideally like this feedback or survey to be attached to the participant record in Civi (i.e. so its easy to see which event they are feeding back on and to find the feedback easily in Civi). I'm not sure if I can see any simple way to do this at the moment.

So I guess the idea would be to send the email as a scheduled reminder with a checksum token to a webform, and also have in the url the event ID. The event id would then allow the user to update their participant record for that event with some custom fields which are the feedback fields (or we could copy a link to the webform submission into a text field).

But to use 1 webform for all events and to pass the event ID to a field of event ID on the form, there is an issue that this will unsubscribe the contact from any other events that they were previously registered for.

Any one got any thoughts on a solution?

Answer (score 3):

We could create an option to disable the unregistering from events as this also solves the problem that if multivalue widgets are enabled for multiple sets of event fieldset, they do not work together well. This way we can get a better control towards the behaviour, also makes the solution possible for any widget.

Regarding the loading event form URL, I think it will also be good to become a checkbox under "Event Registration Options" as people might not want to allow users to change some event setups through URL freely.

Comment: Patch implemented and merged as per suggestion above.

Comment: and the patch is ..... now in webform_civicrm? link? or does this now just work ie the event id can be used in the url? as what? eid=??

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you'd want to set this up would be with a hidden, exposed field for the event. This would allow the value to be selected, but not by the user. It seems that to get this fully functional, the webform-civicrm module will need 2 improvements:

- Allow event id to be specified in the url (note this may already be possible with the use of url tokens in the webform).
- Don't un-register participants if event selector is a hidden field. This seems like a good compromise solution to get the feature you want without removing the un-register behavior for non-hidden fields.

Comment: I believe some of the above has been implemented now so that there is a setting on the Event section of the webform's civicrm tab so that you can 'allow events to be autoloaded from URL'